# Mapstruct 1.2.0 not generating mapper class in springboot 2.0.0.M3 + lombok

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I'm trying to put together a sample project combining the following technologies:

- Spring boot (2.0.0.M3)
- Mapstruct (1.2.0.CR1)
- Lombok (1.16.18)

I have defined this mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SourceToTargetMapper {

    SourceToTargetMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( SourceToTargetMapper.class );

    @Mappings({ 
        @Mapping(source = "characteristics", target = "description"),
        @Mapping(source = "identifier", target = "id") 
    })
    public Target toTarget(Source source);
}
```

The problem I am having is that the class implementing the SourceToTargetMapper interface is not being generated.

That 's the trace I'm getting when i run the unit test:

```
2017-09-04 00:13:24.726 ERROR 1712 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@568bf312] to prepare test instance [io.alfredux.demo.MapperTest@5ccbeb64]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'io.alfredux.demo.MapperTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sourceToTargetMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.alfredux.demo.mapper.SourceToTargetMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.alfredux.demo.mapper.SourceToTargetMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1058) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:567) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

I believe there’s something missing or misplaced in the build/plugin section  of my pom.xml
 file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The source code for the project can be checked here:

https://github.com/Alfredux79/mapstruct-lombock-springboot/tree/stack-overflow-question

The problem can be reproduced downloading the branch and running the command:

```
mvn test
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is how my final version of the pom.xml build section looks like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And with this change the classes are being generated.

The solution was a mix of the answer provided and adding the annotation processor for lombock as well.

Comment: In order to know exactly why this is needed and is working look at my comment [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028450/mapstruct-1-2-0-not-generating-mapper-class-in-springboot-2-0-0-m3-lombok#comment79044312_46028494)

Answer (score 6):

You have not configured your compiler correctly. After running `mvn clean compile`, you should see some files generated by MapStruct under `target/generated-sources`.

You are missing the *maven-compiler-plugin* configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [this example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-field-mapping/pom.xml).

Comment: If I use version 3.1 the project compiles but doesn't generate the mapper clases
If I use a version higher than 3.5 maven cannot detect the lombok generated methods

Comment: The reason why it works with 3.5 and not 3.1 is because the `annotationProcessorPaths` are supported first from 3.5. If the `annotationProcessorPaths` are set than the Maven Compiler uses only the processors that are defined there. Therefore the Lombok processor is not invoked, which leads to it not enabling the flag that MapStruct uses in order to know if the types are complete and ready for processing

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2</version>
     <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below changes in `pom.xml` to make sure to use the latest **m2e-apt** plugin in maven.

```
<properties>
  <!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
  <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
</properties>
```

For eclipse or spring suite IDE support install the official mapstruct plugin.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mapstruct-eclipse-plugin#group-external-install-button

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while using spring boot.

The issue was, on the maven annotation processor path plugin, I had specified the annotation configuration for the MapStruct path but still maven would give the unstaisfied dependency error. The implementation of the mapstruct mapper was being generated. Also my generated annotations folder was present on the classpath. Still no use.

The fix? It was being caused by project lombok. I had NOT used project lombok in my code, but it still ended up on my dependency tree. I specified an annotation configuration path on the pom.xml file for lombok as well, and finally, the damn thing got packaged.

Came *this* close to checking myself into a mental asylum.